# Regexp with sed, alphabetical order without duplicates

Tags: regex, sed

I need an expression which allows letters only in alphabetical order without duplications, white spaces allowed.
For example:

> abc d efg
>   abcd efg
>   bcdefg h

I have to use "sed". Due to that  i cant use lookahead expression.
Sed reads file and in each string must find substring that matches example.
Best i have now is this:

```
sed -nr 's/^[a-g]*(a?b?c?d?e?f?g?)[a-g]*$/\1/gp' test.txt
```

It doesn't work with white spaces, and doesn't work at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -nE '/^a{0,1} *b{0,1} *c{0,1} *d{0,1} *e{0,1} *f{0,1} *g{0,1} *h{0,1} *i{0,1} *j{0,1} *k{0,1} *l{0,1} *m{0,1} *n{0,1} *o{0,1} *p{0,1} *q{0,1} *r{0,1} *s{0,1} *t{0,1} *u{0,1} *v{0,1} *w{0,1} *x{0,1} *y{0,1} *z{0,1} *$/p' file
```

Comment: Thats working. Super cool. Thanks a lot. 
For other people:
If string strongly matches, sed printing it. Otherwise sed doesnt print anything. If you need to print matching substrings you should use key /s  and /g  in sed. When i finish task, i will post my result here

Comment: a ligne may begin by space :

Comment: If you are using -E, you may aswell just use `?` isntead of `{0,1}`

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you try for letters in [a-h] range:

```
sed -nr '/^a? *b? *c? *d? *e? *f? *g? *h? *$/p' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat test.txt |  sed -e "/\([a-z]\).*\1/d" |  grep -E "^ *a* *b* *c* *d* *e* *f* *g* *h* *i* *j* *k* *l* *m* *n* *o* *p* *q* *r* *s* *t* *u* *v* *w* *x* *y* *z* *$"
```

or

```
grep -E "^ *a? *b? *c? *d? *e? *f? *g? *h? *i? *j? *k? *l? *m? *n? *o? *p? *q? *r? *s? *t? *u? *v? *w? *x? *y? *z? *$" test.txt
```

or

```
sed -nE '/^ *a? *b? *c? *d? *e? *f? *g? *h? *i? *j? *k? *l? *m? *n? *o? *p? *q? *r? *s? *t? *u? *v? *w? *x? *y? *z? *$/p' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'h;s/ //g;/(.).*\1/d;s/.*/&\nzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba/;:a;ta;/^\n/!s/^(.)(.*\n.*)\1.*/\2/;ta;/^.+\n/d;x'
```

Copy the line then remove spaces. If the line contains duplicates delete it. Otherwise starting from the front, remove each character in alphabetical order and if successful reinstate the original line. Otherwise delete the line.

Answer (score 0):

`sed -nE 's/[a-z]*(^a{0,1} *b{0,1} *c{0,1} *d{0,1} *e{0,1} *f{0,1} *g{0,1} *h{0,1} *i{0,1} *j{0,1} *k{0,1} *l{0,1} *m{0,1} *n{0,1} *o{0,1} *p{0,1} *q{0,1} *r{0,1} *s{0,1} *t{0,1} *u{0,1} *v{0,1} *w{0,1} *x{0,1} *y{0,1} *z{0,1} *)[a-z]*$/\1/gp' file.txt` 

Was enough for me. Thanks for all. Great answers.